# Windows CMD parse

Tags: windows, cmd, echo, jq

How do I keep the results on the same line?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo {"foo": 0, "foo2": 1} | jq ".foo2, .foo"

1
0
```

Would like to get:

```
1;0
```

Answer (score 0):

One of several alternatives:

```
  jq -r "[.foo2, .foo] | join(\";\")"
```